# How to manipulate the python script to stress CPU by a certain percentage?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, stress-testing

I found a python script online that simulates CPU load. The problem is that it simulates the load at 100%. I want to be able to set the percent parameter based on the user input. How can I do that here?
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Produces load on all available CPU cores

Updated with suggestion to prevent Zombie processes
Linted for Python 3
Source: 
insaner @ https://danielflannery.ie/simulate-cpu-load-with-python/#comment-34130
"""
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

import signal

stop_loop = 0


def exit_chld(x, y):
    global stop_loop
    stop_loop = 1


def f(x):
    global stop_loop
    while not stop_loop:
        x*x


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_chld)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = cpu_count()
    print('-' * 20)
    print('Running load on CPU(s)')
    print('Utilizing %d cores' % processes)
    print('-' * 20)
    pool = Pool(processes)
    pool.map(f, range(processes))
```

I also want to delete the processes so as to free up the usage.

Comment: Don't use all processors. Use the number that divided by processor count is closest to what the user input. The granularity is far from great, meaning that e.g. for one processor, it will be either fully load it or it won't run at all.

Comment: Cant we run all processors at like 50%?

Comment: Using this way, it will keep some of your cores to 100%, so that the average on all cores (excluding other processes) will be close to user input.

Comment: But what if I want to test out on different CPUs? If I test it on a dual core CPU, the minimum percentage will be 50%, can't we specify the stress on the processors?

Comment: Using this approach, no. This is an easy but limited way of achieving the global load.

Comment: Could you tell me how to achieve it then?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you should look for modules that do that.

Comment: How do I restrict the time for which I can run the loop? I tried adding `time.sleep(exec_time)` but the code isn't stopping until I press `ctrl + c`